# How to start remote flow class using RPC in Springboot remote server

Tags: corda

[image]

**Given** that I have Remote Springboot Server that receives HTTP Json from a React Front End.
**When** the `ExampleFlow.Intiaitor.class` is compiled/deployed in the Cordapp in the participant's node.
**Then** how do you remotely start the flow in the Springboot Client using rpcOps?
`rpcOps.startTrackedFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.Initiator.class, iouValue, otherParty)`

Does the Remote Springboot Server need to also compile all the entire Cordapp classes dependencies to reference the .class?

Any examples/samples that fully demonstrate this de-coupling would be appreciated.
(p.s on Corda 4.8/4.9)